# Github API: How to get list of users who have starred a repo AND cloned it

Tags: github-api

I'd like to get a list of users who have starred my public repo and a number of fields related to them such as whether or not they have cloned it. Is this possible with the Github API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The endpoint for stargazers (users who have starred a repo) is documented [here in the documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/). You can follow with additional requests on those users.

Checking whether people have cloned a repo is impossible (you don't even need to be logged in to clone a git / GH repo). You can, however, [list the forks of a repo](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/).

Answer (score 8):

The endpoint for stargazers is:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/stargazers
```

for eg, if you want to get users who starred the repo https://github.com/suhailvs/django-schools/ you can use:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/suhailvs/django-schools/stargazers
```

Answer (score 0):

Github webhook services are fairly detailed and you can really get a lot of information from them but gleaning if someone cloned your repo is a bridge too far. As far as I'm aware, there's no way to track that (you can track new forks). I'd recommend using a webhook to track new repo watches to accomplish at least some of what you're looking for.

Axibase has a tool which leverages Github webhooks, and notifies you via email or instant message (through the messenger of your choice) when someone stars your repository.

The underlying process is here:

[image]

It's a quick setup, the whole process takes less then 10 minutes. Basically you need to create a plaintext file with your email / messenger credentials on your local machine, launch an ATSD sandbox from the terminal, and paste the webhook generated at runtime into the appropriate field on Github. The full process is [here](https://axibase.com/use-cases/integrations/github/watch-notification.html).

Disclaimer: I work for [Axibase](https://axibase.com/)